# Modal - controlling HTML within

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, blacklist

I have a modal window that defaults to a particular URL like somesite.com.

On somesite.com there are 3 links. Is it possible to make it so that I disable one of those links if it's contained in a list of bad URLs? I only have control of the Modal and not somesite.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say modal window, what do you mean? Do you load the somesite.com in an `iframe`. Generally speaking, you'd be better off preparing some sort of example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: No. It's called Cross-Site Scripting and the browser will not allow you to control content on a different site than your script is hosted on. On the bright side, it also means that somesite.com cannot modify your page either.

Comment: Yes, loaded in an iFrame and displayed inside a modal window or lightbox.

Comment: Also, pete, is there another technique that can be utilized? The only alternative I can think of is some sort of native wrapper with a custom browser control. Is this the only way?

Comment: And to clarify, what I need to do is make it so that the URL that 3rd link is meant to go to simply isn't followed. So I don't need to actually change the HTML of the page in the Modal, but rather "IGNORE" it when a user clicks it. Is this still impossible?

Comment: What about using some sort of proxy that will only forward requests that match a whitelist of URLs? Would that work in a Modal/iFrame context?